# is exception handling with spring proxy a code smell?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I've a service containing lots of methods which do http calls using HttpClient. The methods look like:

```
BussinessDomain {

void getPerson(id:String) throws BusinessDomainException {
  ClientResponse res = httpClient.getPerson(id);
  Person p = decodeResponse(res) -> res contains the response body as string; eventually this throws ClientException(some exception specific to HttpClient)
  //... do something with p before returning
  return p;
}

void putPerson(p:Person) throws BusinessDomainException {
  ClientResponse res = httpClient.putPerson(p);
  // same thing, possible to throw ClientException
}

}
```

Since we must only throw BusinessDomainException at this layer, for each method we'd have to  intercept the ClientException and translate it into a BusinessDomainException.

One idea was to use a Spring Proxy around BussinessDomain, but one concern about this approach would be that we'd be externalizing the exception handling outside of the BusinessDomain class.

Do you usually use Spring proxies to do exception handling for your domain layer? Is this approach a good practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at Spring's exception-translation infrastructure?

Comment: I don't know if it's considered a smell or not by purists, but I know that Spring MVC uses this method with  the ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler annotations

Comment: @geoand Not exactly. I think OP is suggesting AOP with `@AfterThrowing`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I know, but aren't Spring's ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler implemented using AOP for exactly the same purpose?

Comment: @geoand No, they aren't implemented with AOP. The handler method is invoked through reflection. If an exception is caught, a different component is dispatched to handle the exception. The process isn't exactly the same and it serves a different purpose than translating exceptions.

Comment: In my opinion, although there will be some code duplication, consider writing one ore more abstract base classes for your  business objects which wrap each call and do the translation. This way, you won't be dependent on Spring if you ever decide to change.

Comment: Getting information about a person by HTTP doesn't sound like a business domain task to me.